# Is it possible to merge the two cells of the same line in a table in a Google text Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have a table in a text document in Google Docs. Is it possible to merge two cells  of the same line (as we do in sheets)? If so, how?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from [TableCell.merge()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-cell#merge%28%29)

```
// Assume we've already located our table
var tableRow = table.getChild(0); // gets first row
var tableCell = tableRow.getChild(3); // gets fourth cell in row
tableCell.merge(); // Merges fourth cell with third cell.
```

Comment: Hi more one time, @Mogsdad. But I was asking (maybe in the wrong forum) how to merge it using the google docs own interface, ie, without coding. I don't find no button in my google docs do to this merge in google docs text table.

Comment: True, there isn't. Code is the only way.

Comment: That as a feature request is all over the place in the Google Docs product forums.